# treating json like an array

Tags: json

I was doing some test with json and ran into several issues. hope somebody on this mailing list can help out.

```
localStorage[LOC] = JSON.stringify(track);
            var boy = localStorage[LOC];
            alert(boy);
```

This is the data I get back

```
[{"lat":42.5877511,"lng":-71.7873177,"acc":67,"date":"Sat Apr 14 2012 01:03:46 GMT-0400 (EDT)"}]
```

I was wondering how I could access the json objects like we do in a regular array.

For debugging purposes I did something like,

```
alert(boy[0].lat);
```

But the result I got back was undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the string through `JSON.parse()` to get back your object:

```
var boy = JSON.parse(localStorage[LOC]);
```

`JSON.parse()` is essentially the opposite of `JSON.stringify()`. You run `stringify` to turn an object into a string for local storage, and when you pull the string back out of local storage, you run `parse` to turn the string back into an object.

Comment: Thank you very much! you are awesome Delan and you just saved my night!